# Redshift - Merging two columns

Tags: sql, string, merge, concatenation, amazon-redshift

I have two columns that have customer name and product name. I would like to merge these two columns with a ' - ' between them.

Could anyone advice as to how to do this. I am using Redshift. I tried `concat` and `string_agg` but I am trying to see if there is an alternate way without the `group by`.

```
customer_name, product_name, expected_output
Kev, Prod_A, Kev - Prod_A
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use the `||` concatenation operator as @Mureinik has mentioned.  But, we can also use the `CONCAT` function here:

```
SELECT
    customer_name,
    product_name,
    CONCAT(CONCAT(customer_name, ' - '), product_name) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

My guess as to why `CONCAT` wasn't working for you is that you were trying to pass more than 2 parameters to it.  `CONCAT` in Redshift only takes two parameters, so we must chain them here to make it work.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `||` operator to concatenate strings:

```
SELECT customer_name, product_name, customer_name || ' - ' || product_name AS output
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: But be aware that if any of the columns you're concatenating is `NULL` the result will turn `NULL` eg. `SELECT 'foo' || 'bar' || 'baz' || NULL;`